# Jdbc datagaurd issue

Tags: oracle, jdbc, dataguard

I have implemented the datagaurd in Oracle database for high
    availability with two servers and configured the jdbc settings to
    connect Jboss application server to always connect  primary database
    instance.

If I use the following string:

```
<connection-url>
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<ip1>)(PORT=<port>))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<ip2>)(PORT=<port>)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME
= MYDB)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SELECT)(METHOD=BASIC))))</connection-url>
```

When i perform a switch-over/filover the ip1 is down and ip2 is up. If I specify ip2 first in my list then I get a connection (just like I'd expect if I just tried to connect to ip2). However when I put ip1 first I get the same error as if I tried to connect directly to

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown
in progress
```

Comment: Edit your question if you have additional information, don't use comments for that.

Comment: There is too much to quote here, but if you'll check "Database High Availability Best Practices", section 10.1 discusses configuration of JDBC clients for auto failover. See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HABPT/config_fcf.htm#HABPT4969

Comment: Are you using Active Data Guard? If not your standby might be in mount mode.

Comment: yes, we are not using active data guard setup. Do we need to ensure   that only the listener at the present primary server is running or else that the client connections are directed to the standby
database. Is Jdbc connection pooling will ensure no new  connections to failed node and clean up of current  active connections  to failed node.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended connection URL for a Data Guard with RAC is as shown below.  Can you make sure that you are using the correct connection URL ?

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (FAILOVER=on)
     (CONNECT_TIMEOUT= 15) (RETRY_COUNT=20) (RETRY_DELAY=3)
       (ADDRESS_LIST =
           (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
           (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST=primary-scan) (PORT=1521)))
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
             (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
             (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST=secondary-scan) (PORT=1521))) 
      (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME = gold-cloud-service-name)))
```